# Is it safe to store passwords in WhatsApp end-to-end encrypted backup?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, encryption, password, google-backup

So there is a WhatsApp group in which only I am present and hence I use the group to store my passwords by sending them in the group as chats. I then backup those chats using the WhatsApp end-to-end encrypted Google Drive Backup. But is it safe to store my passwords this way? I mean it is end-to-end encrypted so even if there is a data breach my passwords would be encrypted and they would be safe, right?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Besides that the backup is password encrypted there seem to be no details on the security and the used algorithms of the encryption. Therefore I would not recommend this as password storage. Better use a tool that uses Keepass based database or other known to be secure formats. Apps like Keepass2Android can auto sync database to Dropbox or similar cloud storage and offer password entering keyboard on Android.

Comment: Is Keepass2Android better than Bitwarden?

Comment: That depends on what security properties you want to achieve. I have set-up Keepass in a way that even if someone gets access to my Dropbox account containing the database it is impossible to hack the database because it requires not only the password but also a secret file that is not stored online (I have manually copied that file among my devices). Also you can choose the key generation iterations and algorithm to enhance security. I am not familiar with Bitwarden, but I assume it only uses a password to secure he password data so everything depends on the strength of the password only.